# Symfony datetimetype modifying posted time

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, symfony-forms

I have simple form like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('publishSince', DateTimeType::class, [
            'format' => \DateTime::ATOM,
            'widget' => 'single_text',
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => ItemPublishDTO::class,
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ]);
}
```

And DTO:

```
class ItemPublishDTO
{
    /**
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual("now")
     */
    public $publishSince;
}
```

When I post form in tests with value "2020-01-08T00:08:00+00:00" which is UTC
Symfony form returns: "2020-01-08T00:01:00+00:00"

It's moved by 7min but why? Server timezone is also UTC.

**Corection**: Time part is always lost and set to 00:01:00 no matter what I send.

I track error here:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.3/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer.php#L123

Returned timestamp is wrong.

Comment: What type field in db? How publishSince annotation looks like?

Comment: There is no database interaction, just filling plain DTO.

Comment: And how DTO knows that publishSince is the DateTime, not just Date?

Comment: That's done by form. Form will validate this. As far as debug this it looks like bug in DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer.